# Invoking ffmpeg iteratively

Tags: find, ffmpeg

I call ffmpeg like this from Mac's terminal:

```
$ find . -type f -name *.webm | while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$f"; ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.webm}".mp4 2> ~/Desktop/err; done
```

Only the first file returned by find gets processed:

> ./artist/Moody Blues/_vid/Nights in white satin_lyrics.webm

Excerpt from err:

> Enter command: |all |-1 [ ]
>
> Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string 's [360p].webm'
>
> Enter command: |all |-1 [ ]
>   Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string 'hannel/Ash Wainman/_Inbox/BOHEMIAN RHAPSODY - ASH WAINMAN[HD,1280x720].webm'

We should have 'channel' rather than 'hannel'.

Comment: My *guess* is that although you are correctly quoting `"$f"` to prevent filename expansion by the *shell*, `ffmpeg` itself is treating part of the filename as a pattern for expansion. You may find something relevant here [FFmpeg formats](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html)

Comment: There is not dash before channel: ./channel

Comment: It looks like `ffmpeg` is entering interactive mode.

Comment: Try `$ find . -type f -name "*.webm" | while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$f"; ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$f" "${f%.webm}".mp4 2> ~/Desktop/err; done`

Comment: How do I mark this questn 'solved'?

Comment: There should be a check mark next to each answer. Click on it / select it with your mouse, and note the change of color - taht should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're improperly using `find` and needlessly creating a shell loop (it hurts to read!), because you can (should) run `ffmpeg` directly from inside `find`:

```
find . -type f -name *.webm \
-exec sh -c 'echo "$1"; ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$1" "${1%.webm}".mp4 2>> ~/Desktop/err' sh {} ';'
```

With deference to LordNeckBeard (though mine is assuredly hairier).

Answer (score 1):

As LordNeckBeard suggests, adding `-nostdin` stops `ffmpeg` from attempting interaction (or, apparently, reading its inherited stdin.)

This is touched on in the man page:

```
-stdin
       Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless standard input is used as an input. To explicitly disable interaction you need to specify "-nostdin".

       Disabling interaction on standard input is useful, for example, if ffmpeg is in the background process group. Roughly the same result can be achieved with "ffmpeg ... <
       /dev/null" but it requires a shell.
```